# How to use the Click event in a GridViewColumn on a WPF TreeView/ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

Currently I have some `GridViewColumns` such as this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="20">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="X" />
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="18"
                Height="18"
                Source="{Binding VisibleIcon}"
                Opacity="{Binding VisibleOpacity}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

where I want to do something on the item that's clicked on this column. But I don't know how to add the `Click` event because neither `GridViewColumn` nor `Image` has a `Click` event.

I was hoping for something like this:

```
void ClickEvent ...
{
    SelectLayer (boundDataItem);
    // boundDataItem is of type `Layer`.
}
```

EDIT: I found a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event but that doesn't give me the clicked bound data item, can only get the image or text but they aren't unique for an image to lookup.

EDIT2: Another thing is even with `MouseLeftButtonDown` it only works if I click on the `TextBlock` itself, not outside it even within the same `GridViewColumn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the handler on your root element (`StackPanel.MouseLeftButtonDown`), then in your handler you can get to the bound item using `var layer = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Layer`.

Comment: That's wicked man, it works. One question you might know is, it correctly registers mouse clicks on the stackpanel items within the item limits/extents. But not outside the item extents, which makes sense as the even is on the StackPanel. I was wondering if I could register the click even wherever in that particular column is clicked? As in still getting the same clicked items but whether they are clicked directly or the same row they exist. Should I try to make the item length (TextBlock part) as big as the gridviewcolumn?

Comment: Unfortunately that's going to be more difficult because the GridViewRowPresenter only gives each element as much size as it requests. If static widths are OK, you can set the width of the StackPanel directly. If not, you can fake it out by using Grids and SharedSizeGroup - I can give an example if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried setting the Width of the StackPanel and it shifted the items as if there is a space to their left. This is a TreeView control so it looks awkward to have the items in the center, instead of aligned to left. is this what you meant?

Comment: First off, set the background color of the StackPanel to e.g. blue so you know how wide it is. Then you'll probably see that the TextBlock is Centered in the StackPanel (I'm not sure why this would be; the default is Left). But the TreeView is a different story. You probably don't want a static width; you want each node to extend to the edge of the TreeView. A hacky way to do it would be to set the StackPanel width to 9999 and limit the width of the TreeView. As for a good way... that might be worth its own question.

Comment: Thanks man I will give it a try if it doesn't work as good, I will ask a new question and will post a comment here.

Comment: Hey look, someone asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740655/dragging-and-dropping-treeviewitems-in-non-clickable-area-of-treeview-wpf). publicgk's answer is about making the TreeView content stretch, so that should work for you. Unfortunately you have to re-template the TreeViewItem, which is what I was afraid of, but you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: Thanks, I just looked at his answer but it didn't make much sense to me. Do I need all that ControlTemplate xaml code to make the TV content stretch?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. WPF makes you do that sometimes, and when it does, it sucks.