# Dragging and dropping TreeViewItems in non-clickable area of TreeView [WPF]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, drag-and-drop

A question about dragging and dropping tree view items in WPF.

My original question is a little complex. So I simplified it, and here is the code:
XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseMove" Handler="TreeNode_MouseMove"/>
                <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Drop" Handler="TreeNode_Drop"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <TreeViewItem Header="first node in the tree"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="second node in the tree"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="third node in the tree"></TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TreeNode_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, DateTime.Now.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private void TreeNode_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = (string)e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is very simple, just pop up a message box when one tree view item is dragged and dropped on another tree view item.

When I drop it right on another item, it works fine, like this:

[image]

But if I drag it slightly off the boundary of the item, it does not work, like this:

[image]

The mouse cursor is displayed as a “forbidden sign”, sorry I can’t get it in the screen shot.

So now my question is: how to make the second condition work? How to make the Drop event still fire up when the dropping location is slightly off the boundary of the item?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use AllowDrop property and Drop event for TreeView itself.

this is from msdn: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4b8bafe5-ae3e-439d-953a-f534a60dbb2d/

Answer (score 2):

Take the default `ControlTemplate` of `TreeViewItem` and make the `Border` (the border which contains the ContentPresenter) to have a colspan of 2, e.g.:

```
<Border
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
            Name="Bd"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

Note that the whole area in TreeViewItem next to the TextBlock would become *clickable*. You may want to play around with the template to fit it to your needs.

[image]

Below is the ControlTemplate of TreeViewItem extracted using [Dump Control Template Utility](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/essential-tools-for-the-wpf-novice/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ControlTemplate
    TargetType="TreeViewItem" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="Auto"
                MinWidth="19" />
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton
            IsChecked="False"
            ClickMode="Press"
            Name="Expander">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style
                    TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <ResourceDictionary />
                    </Style.Resources>
                    <Setter
                        Property="UIElement.Focusable">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter
                        Property="FrameworkElement.Width">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <s:Double>19</s:Double>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter
                        Property="FrameworkElement.Height">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <s:Double>13</s:Double>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter
                        Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate
                                TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Border
                                    Background="#00FFFFFF"
                                    Width="19"
                                    Height="13">
                                    <Border
                                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                                        CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"
                                        BorderBrush="#FF7898B5"
                                        Width="9"
                                        Height="9"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush
                                                StartPoint="0,0"
                                                EndPoint="1,1">
                                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStop
                                                        Color="#FFFFFFFF"
                                                        Offset="0.2" />
                                                    <GradientStop
                                                        Color="#FFC0B7A6"
                                                        Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Path
                                            Data="M0,2L0,3 2,3 2,5 3,5 3,3 5,3 5,2 3,2 3,0 2,0 2,2z"
                                            Fill="#FF000000"
                                            Name="ExpandPath"
                                            Margin="1,1,1,1" />
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger
                                        Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked">
                                        <Setter
                                            Property="Path.Data"
                                            TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <StreamGeometry>M0,2L0,3 5,3 5,2z</StreamGeometry>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Trigger.Value>
                                            <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                                        </Trigger.Value>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Border
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
            Name="Bd"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentPresenter
                Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                ContentSource="Header"
                Name="PART_Header"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Border>
        <ItemsPresenter
            Name="ItemsHost"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger
            Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded">
            <Setter
                Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                TargetName="ItemsHost">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <x:Static
                        Member="Visibility.Collapsed" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger
            Property="ItemsControl.HasItems">
            <Setter
                Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                TargetName="Expander">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <x:Static
                        Member="Visibility.Hidden" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger
            Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
            <Setter
                Property="Panel.Background"
                TargetName="Bd">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource
                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource
                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition
                    Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
                    <Condition.Value>
                        <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                    </Condition.Value>
                </Condition>
                <Condition
                    Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive">
                    <Condition.Value>
                        <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                    </Condition.Value>
                </Condition>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter
                Property="Panel.Background"
                TargetName="Bd">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource
                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource
                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger
            Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
            <Setter
                Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource
                        ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks. and here is a easier way: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4b8bafe5-ae3e-439d-953a-f534a60dbb2d/

Comment: @CuiPengFei, if its an easier and correct way, post it as an answer. Then after sometime, accept your own answer. This will help future visitors at this page (with similar problem statement) to easily locate the better answer.

Comment: @CuiPengFei, you may want to unaccept this and accept the other answer.